# Start a Java process at low priority using Runtime.exec / ProcessBuilder.start?

Tags: java, windows, processbuilder, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to start an external process via Java using the ProcessBuilder class, and that much works. Currently running using the command:

```
new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", jarfile, args);
```

What I would like to do is just this, but to start the process with low priority. My program is currently only running on Windows, so a window-specific solution is fine by me. Some research suggests I use the "start" command, but when I try doing this from Java it gives an exception saying it is an unrecognized command (the same command works from cmd.exe).

Does anyone know how to launch a process from Java (Windows-specific if need be), with `belownormal` priority?

Comment: because `start` is not executable, but internal command of `cmd.exe`

Comment: The only thing i can think of is to wrap it in .bat and in the bat file use start

Comment: I think you meant .cmd instead of .bat

Comment: @OpDeCirkel, i have a question. I never knew about start command affecting process priority. If i want to have admin access, so let's say i am on elevated cmd line, then if i use start jar-file, then also my file will be running with low priority but with elevated rights, right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [start command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true). It is windows dependent but does what you need. I [have read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865610/cross-platform-way-to-change-java-process-priority) there is no cross platform way for this.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C start /B /belownormal javaws -version");
System.out.println("Before start");
Process start = pb.start();
```

It is even possible to read Input end Error streams.

To wait:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C start /B /belownormal /WAIT javaws -sdasd");
System.out.println("Before start");
Process start = pb.start();
start.waitFor();
System.out.println("Done");
```

For premature destroy:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C start /B /belownormal /WAIT javaws -sdasd");
System.out.println("Before start");
Process start = pb.start();
start.destroy();
start.waitFor();

System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: While this does run the process in low priority as requested it creates a disconnect between the Process object and the actual java payload. Which means that with /C it appears to finish immediately (allowing a new job to be picked up leading to massive spam of work), or with /K it persists and appears to never finish even though the payload has completed.

Comment: The expected running behaviour can be restored by adding /wait to the start command and removing /b, however, the Process.destroy() method remains ineffectual.

Comment: Standard Admins Answer #1 Works on my computer.

See my edits. 

Maybe your third party app ignores kill signal -- than this is topic for another question. How to prevent blocking kill signal for process in windows.

Comment: Substituted with "Before start" to make this output more clear.

Comment: A destroy on the process will not necessarily kill the subprocess. Using the winp library should provide a better solution: http://winp.kohsuke.org/