# Some questions about Java Threads and Process Priorities

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, unix

I have a small question about threads. 
On Unix systems, we have `nice`, which can be used to set priorities 
processes. 
OK, on ​​my system, I call some external processes, however, I would like to 
set priority for them. 
In unix, I could call other ProcessBuilder and set the nice to 
process I want, but in Windows, it is not possible.

If I start a thread with some priority, and use within ProcessBuilder 
it, the process will have the same priority as thread?
Or is there some other way to do this?

Cheers

Comment: Hi caarlos0, don't have a clear answer on this as I'm not familiar with the particular function you're trying to replicate but in the windows task manager you can right click a process and give it priority or processor affinity.

Comment: Also found a few more potentially helpful links: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority_what.shtml http://slashdot.org/story/06/09/03/2231244/Permanently-Set-Process-Priority-in-Windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to set priority on a process (`Process`) level in Java.

> ***If I start a thread with some priority, and use `ProcessBuilder` within it, the process will have the same priority as thread? Or is there some other way to do this?***

The process will run side by side with the JVM, so it will not inherit the *threads* priority. It will be scheduled on it's own by the operating system.

As stated above, there is no built in cross-platform way of tweaking the priority of a process, but there is a [`Thread.setPriority(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority%28int%29) though. So perhaps you could do the work by the external program in a separate *thread* (instead of starting a new process) and use the `setPriority` method on this thread.

#### Related questions / answers:

- [Cross-platform way to change java process priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865610/cross-platform-way-to-change-java-process-priority)
- [How to change the priority of a running java process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239142/how-to-change-the-priority-of-a-running-java-process)

Comment: Just to add to this, this will only set priority on the thread in the Java Virtual Machine. You can't affect the threads priorities from the OS level.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a C/C++ DLL and export a JNI function that calls [SetPriorityClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You could then use this in your java code