# Increase a Java application's priority above 10

Tags: java, thread-priority

First time asking questions at **stackoverflow**!

I've been asked to increase one Java application's priority to 15...
I know that Thread class,  Max_PRIORITY equals 10...

Scenario: This java application runs on a server which runs other C applications, all of them with realtime priority something like 15.

Thanks for the help!

Edit: Windows Server 2012 64 bits

Edit 2: They think that the java application is not getting too much cpu share, when compared too the C applications...

Edit 3: This java application needs to run at a realtime priority, like the c applications. 24 is their priorities, please forget when I told 15.

Comment: This is a job for the operating system.  Thread priority is unlikely to correspond to process priority.  That said, “15” is meaningless without context.  What is 15?  On what operating system is the Java application running?

Comment: Thread priority has nothing to do with process priority, and process priority is meaningless without telling us what operating system you're referring to.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to do so. Windows Server 2012, 64 bits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some questions about Java Threads and Process Priorities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416029/some-questions-about-java-threads-and-process-priorities)

Comment: Please guys check again, i just edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You should read more about the VM you are using in your office.

A regular Java thread has a priority range from 1 to 10. You can use a real time thread and can set its priority above 10. These regular java threads can be created using **java.lang.Thread** class

To create a realtime thread, you need a JVM that can work with **javax.realtime** package. You will have to download a jar which includes javax.realtime package. There aren't many RTSJ (Real time specification for Java) implementation. One such JVM that implements RTSJ is **JamaicaVM**.

Posix can allow you to create different thread scheduling policies and priorities. The SCHED_FIFO policy provides 99 different priority levels.

Below is a link where a Realtime thread has been created using the WebSphere Real Time VM.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-rtj3/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: glad, i could help.

Answer (score 1):

Just to supplement above answer,other  Real time Java VM's are

1. TimeSys RTSJ Reference Implementation
2. IBM WebSphere Real Time
3. OVM
4. JamaicaVM
5. jRate
6. Aonix PERC
7. Rockit Real-Time
8. LJRT
9. FijiVM

src: http://rtjava.blogspot.com