# Start a process (using Runtime.exec / ProcessBuilder.start) with low priority

Tags: java, linux, scheduling, processbuilder

I need to start a CPU-intensive system process under low priority so that it doesn't slow down my server. How can I do this on Linux?

This is similar to this question: [Start a Java process at low priority using Runtime.exec / ProcessBuilder.start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223765/start-a-java-process-using-runtime-exec-processbuilder-start-with-low-priori) except on Linux instead of Windows. It's OK if the process's priority is changed after the process is started (as long as there isn't much delay).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run the command using [`/usr/bin/nice`](http://amath.colorado.edu/computing/software/man/nice.html).  For instance:

```
$ /usr/bin/nice -n 10 somecommand arg1 arg2
```

will run `somecommand arg1 arg2` at a niceness of +10.  (In Unix / Linux, a larger niceness value results in a lower scheduler priority.  The range of `nice` is typically from -19 to +19.)

Note that this solution is platform specific.  It will only work on Linux and Unix systems ...

---

**FOLLOW UP**

The ProcessBuilder should be instantiated as you would any normal command; i.e.

```
    new ProcessBuilder("nice", "-n", "10", "somecommand", "arg1", "arg2");
```

There's no black magic about when / how to split commands / arguments.  The command (e.g. `nice`) syntax determines what it arguments should be, and that determines both how they should quoted on the shell command line, and how they should be provided when using `ProcessBuilder` (or the native `exec*` syscalls of that matter).

I don't think that there should be problems with `waitFor()` etc, because (AFAIK) the `/usr/bin/nice` command uses `exec` (not `fork` / `exec`) to run the supplied command.  Try it out ...

Comment: How should I pass this to ProcessBuilder? new ProcessBuilder("nice", "-n", "10", "somecommand", "arg1", "arg2") or new ProcessBuilder("nice", "-n", "10", "somecommand arg1 arg2")? Will it be free of any problems with waitfor() and destroy() that the Windows solution exhibited?