# Setting nice value of Java program running on linux

Tags: java, linux, thread-priority

I want my Java program to lower it's priority some so it doesn't overwhelm the system. My initial thought was to use `Thread.currentThread().setPriority(5)` but that appears to be merely its priority within the JVM.

Then I thought maybe I'd cludge it and invoke a system command, but `Thread.getId()` is also merely the JVM's id, so I don't even know what process id to pass to `renice`.

Is there any way for a Java program to do something like this?

Comment: Related question: [Cross-platform way to change java process priority](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2865610/772981), no positive answer.

Answer (score 5):

Since we must do it in a platform dependent way, I run a shell process from java and it renices its parent. The parrent happens to be our java process.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Pid
{
  public static void main(String sArgs[])
    throws java.io.IOException, InterruptedException
  {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
      new String[] {
        "sh",
        "-c",
        "renice 8 `ps h -o ppid $$`"
        // or: "renice 8 `cat /proc/$$/stat|awk '{print $4}'`"
      }
      );
    // we're done here, the remaining code is for debugging purposes only
    p.waitFor();
    BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      p.getErrorStream()));
    System.out.println(bre.readLine());
    BufferedReader bro = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      p.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println(bro.readLine());
    Thread.sleep(10000);
  }
}
```

BTW: are you Brad Mace from jEdit? Nice to meet you.

Answer (score 4):

If your program is the only running java program, then you can run

```
renice +5 `pgrep java`
```

Comment: This assumes that [process nice-ness affects Java thread priority](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786492/does-nice-affect-the-priority-of-java-threads).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to renice - you may also use ionice comand. For example :

```
ionice -c 3 -n 7 -p PID
```

Comment: That still requires knowing the process ID

Answer (score 2):

Also look at https://github.com/jnr/jnr-posix/.

This POSIX library should allow you to get at some of the Linux Posix *Nice* functions like...

https://github.com/jnr/jnr-posix/blob/master/src/main/java/jnr/posix/LibC.java for the OS level setPriority(), i.e. [setpriority(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setpriority)

jnr-posix is also in Maven.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
nice --adjustment=5 java whatever
```

to run your java program and assign the priority in just one step.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to invoke your java application from a bash script or start/stop service script then find the process id after startup and renice it.