# Change priority of java.lang.Process

Tags: java, windows

I create a Process using the java.lang.ProcessBuilder. 
The target is an exe-file(using windows here) with some arguments.

This process is very CPU intensive, so I wan't it to run at low priority.

Is there a way to do this from java?

System independent solution would be better but Windows would do.

It is important, that it is started without a window.

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865610/cross-platform-way-to-change-java-process-priority

Comment: This may help: http://superuser.com/questions/620724/changing-windows-process-priority-via-command-line